# Eclipse C++ slow execution

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to use Eclipse to develop C++ applications with the CDT plugin (JDT was already installed previously). For a simple HelloWorld application, the build time is actually nice (<1 s), but then it takes around 5 s to actually run the generated .exe file.

The same program in Visual Studio runs almost instantly. Any suggestions on what might be causing this slow behaviour in Eclipse?

Comment: In Eclipse, launched what and how? What you get on the command line doing the same?

Comment: `.exe`? - so you are on Windows. In Windows Defender, did you exclude the Eclipse installation directory (it's a known issue that Windows Defender slows down Java applications, which might also be true for child processes as in your case)?